# How to associate a file with an editor in Fex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

Within FlashBuilder it is possible to open a media file (such as an image) by right clicking on the file then selecting Open With and then choosing from a list of applications to open the file with the most appropriate editor. The trouble with this approach is that it is time consuming and has to be repeated whenever a similar file type needs to be edited from within FlashBuilder. 
How can I associate a file (e.g. audio.png) with an editor (e.g. Photoshop) to permanently connect the file type with the application thus ending the process of selecting the application every time a similar file type has to be edited.

Comment: I'm very confused as to what you want; and based on the answers no one quite understands this either.  First off, are you referring to Flex (a programming SDK) or Flash Builder (An IDE)?

Comment: It's just a Flash Builder configuration question. He wants to set the default editor to an external program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to settings under Window->Preferences->General->Editors->File Associations.

Add a new file type (Add button near top of dialog).

Add a new "Associated Editor" in the bottom portion of that dialog. (Second Add button towards bottom.)

Select "External Programs" after clicking "Add" to pick whatever program.

Answer (score 1):

you can associate file types with your app by using the `<fileTypes>` tag in your descriptor-app.xml ([read here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f2fea1812938a6e463-8000.html#WSfffb011ac560372f2fea1812938a6e463-7fdd)). Or use `NativeApplication.setAsDefaultApplication()` ([read here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeApplication.html#setAsDefaultApplication%28%29)), However, you can not make another application the default in flex.

Comment: Do you mean that every time I want to edit a graphics file from within Flex I have to select Open With and scroll down the list to find the appropriate editor?

Comment: I think at this point we need more clarity in what your trying to do.

My instructions are for code to make an application that can associate itself with certain file types.

@drkstr1's instructions are for using Flash Builder (a Flex IDE) to open files.

You can also set the default application at the OS level by right clicking the file, selecting properties and clicking "Change" under the general tab.  (Instructions for windows, if your using Mac or Linux, I cant help)

Comment: CyanAngel, I can right click the file and select Properties, but there is no General tab to select and no Change option.

Comment: @SimonRH You must right click the file and bring up propertie sin windows Explorer to access the general tab; not within Flash Builder.

Comment: Don't think this is an Air or Flex SDK question-- Flash Builder/Eclipse stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Flash Builder is just an Eclipse plugin.

Here are the instructions to do what you are asking in eclipse.

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-51.xhtml

> Associating editors with file types To associate editors with various
>   file types in the Workbench:
>
> Open the  command link General > Editors > File Associations
>   preference page.
>
> Select the file type from the File types list, or click Add to add a
>   type that is not already on the list.
>
> In the Associated editors list, select the editor that you want to
>   associate with that file type. To add an editor to the list:
>
> - Click Add. The Editor Selection dialog box opens.
> - Select Internal Editors or External Programs, depending on whether the editor that you want was built for the Workbench or runs outside
>     the Workbench.
> - If you select External Programs, you can click the Browse button to browse the file system.
> - Select the editor from the list and click OK.
>
> Click OK to finish associating the editor with the selected file type.
>   When you associate an internal editor with a file type, that editor
>   opens in the editor area of the Workbench. For example, if you
>   double-click a file in the Project Explorer or an entry in the
>   Bookmarks or Tasks view it opens in the editor area.